# Hide the keybord on clicking enter button or search button

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've added the `UISearchBar` button inside the `UIBarButtonItem` inside the toolbar button.

In the below form:

```
// search bar
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
[searchBar release];

[buttons addObject:searchBarButtonItem];
```

Now the problem in when I click on the `UISearchBar` keyboard appears. I'd like to hide the keyboard on clicking in enter or search button. How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement a method from `UISearchBarDelegate`:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to process the [`UISearchBarDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) methods.

In the following methods, call `-resignFirstResponder` method of UISearchBar.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

The detail of above delegate methods can be found in [the Apple official document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate). I often resign first responder inside those delegate methods as the end of searching.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use UISEarchBar's delegate method

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and for enter (not tested)

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;   // called when text changes (including clear)
{
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@"\n"])
               [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 1):

In the header file, add or connect to the UISearchBar outlet: should look something like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBarName;
```

Then, in the implementor, add the following:

```
self.searchBarName.delegate = self;
```

in the `viewDidLoad` function.

Then add the following function:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchBarName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Also as mentioned above ensure that this is added/extended in the header
 UISearchBarDelegate

Answer (score 0):

use `[textField endEditing:YES];`, it should work for you, or you can create an oject of ur button and do `[self.buttonObj resignFirstResponder]`